# WooCommerce / WordPress removes HTML attributes from hooks

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to add custom attributes to product label in WooCommerce cart
Here's what I'm using

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'woo_api_cart_item_name', 10, 3 );

function woo_api_cart_item_name($item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key){

 (... some code)

 if($status == "NEW"){
    if(isset($cart_item["clientDesignURL"]))
    {
        $item_name.= " <span style='color:red;' >✕</span> <a style='color:white;' href='".$cart_item["clientDesignURL"]."' class='clientDesignURLButton'> Customize</a>";
    }
    else
    {
        $item_name.= "<p   onclick='myCustomFunctionB()' class='clientDesignURLError'>-</p>";
    }
 }
 else{
    $item_name .= "<span onclick='myCustomFunctionA()' style='color:green;' class='".$cart_item["clientDesignID"]."'>✓ <img src='".$decoded_response->thumbUrl."'/></span>";
 }

return $item_name;
}
```

I'm trying to add button next to every item in cart which does something in ajax. Problem is that woocommerce / wordpress removes "onclick" attribute.

I've tried other tags but all of them are removed. [Browser inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUnQc.png)
Changing theme doesn't work. I've checked all plugins and it didn't work either.
Trying other tags like

doesn't work (whole  tag got removed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'wp_kses_allowed_html', 'prefix_filter_allowed_html', 10, 2 );
/**
     * Add "onclick" to allowed KSES output.
     *
     * @param $allowed
     * @param $context
     * @return mixed
     */
function prefix_filter_allowed_html( $allowed, $context ) {
    if ( 'post' === $context ) {
        $allowed['p']['onclick'] = true;
    }

    return $allowed;
}
```

Add onclick attribute to allowed HTML for `<p>` tag